# I am trying to post on the users Facebook wall directly with his permissions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on the users Facebook wall directly with his
 permissions in Jquery, can anyone help me.I have read all the articles
 but they are in php.   I need to publish a post on at least 10 users'
 wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you need to use with the js sdk is this:

```
FB.api(
    "/me/feed",
    "POST",
    {
        "message": "This is a test message"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Notice that before doing this call you need the user access token, that grant you the permission to post on the wall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,Can i replace me in "/me/feed" with Userid like  "/Userid/feed"

Comment: Yes, you can, whenever you have those permission.